# Invariant names and submodels of forcing extensions

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

*EDIT: There are serious problems with the definition below; see the comment thread below for those problems and some thoughts on addressing them. I'm leaving the question up for now since I think the **idea** is still interesting, but it is definitely broken at the moment.*

---

Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a forcing notion and $\nu$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name. Say that a $\mathbb{P}$-name $\mu$ is *$\nu$-invariant* if, whenever $G, H$ are $\mathbb{P}$-generic and $\nu[G]=\nu[H]$, then $\mu[G]=\mu[H]$. OK fine, that's nonsense, but it's easy to fix: formally, $\mu$ is $\nu$-invariant if whenever $\mathbb{Q}$ is a forcing notion and $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-names which are forced to be $\mathbb{P}$-generic and have $\nu[\gamma_0]=\nu[\gamma_1]$, then it is forced that $\mu[\gamma_0]=\mu[\gamma_1]$.

Say further that a name $\mu$ is *hereditarily $\nu$-invariant* if it and each name in its transitive closure is $\nu$-invariant, and let $HI_\nu$ denote the class of hereditarily $\nu$-invariant $\mathbb{P}$-names.

If $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic, then it's not hard to show that $\{\mu[G]: \mu\in HI_\nu\}$ is a model of ZF; call it "$V[G]_\nu$". My question is this:

> Does the model $V[G]_\nu$ have a snappy description as HOD of something, or as a symmetric submodel? By Grigorieff we know that it is such a model; but I don't immediately see how to *describe* it nicely as such.

(I'm particularly interested in the case when $\nu$ is a name for a set of reals, if that matters.)

I'm interested in the $HI_\nu$-construction because it gibes nicely with ideas from computability theory - specifically on a recasting of Steel forcing I've used, but also other things - and it makes a couple arguments I'm working on nicer. Of course, it has no broader mathematical value since there are provably no models of this form which aren't of better-known forms; but it's still something I find neat.

Comment: To be sure, a natural guess is $HOD(V\cup tc(\nu[G]))^{V[G]}$, but I don't see how to show that this is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately for all of us, Grigorieff's work about finding the "generating set" (this $\nu[G]$ you seek) is negative in the sense that his proofs really just apply "almost abstract nonsense" in the form of the Reflection theorem. Almost good news, though, Yair Hayut and I have worked out a structure theorem for symmetric extensions as part of a recent work; not good news, though, we ditched it in favor of a far simpler notion that gave us cleaner results. It's half-written somewhere...

Comment: So, are you interested in some specific $\Bbb P$, or at least some constraints on $\Bbb P$ (e.g. homogeneity assumptions, or something like that)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Re: Grigorieff's theorem, yeah :(. I'd be super interested in the structure theorem you and Yair wrote up - is that available anywhere? As to which $\mathbb{P}$ I'm interested in, there is a specific one (and a specific $\nu$), but I'm really interested in the general case: the invariant-names construction is in the spirit of stuff I've done before in higher reverse mathematics, and feels more computability-theoretic to me than HOD, and much more than symmetric submodels. In lieu of full generality, I'd be happy to understand the homogeneous (or weakly homogeneous) case, though.

Comment: Well, we have a very... erm... basic write up. Probably riddled with inaccuracies, but I'll see him later this week, and I'll ask him if it's okay to send you a copy. As far as this go, the "invariant-names are more natural to me" sounds exactly like "Go symmetric extensions!", which is good. :-)

Comment: Also, do you have an example of a nontrivial model of this form? Just by looking at this definition, the hereditary requirement seems a bit... fishy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, $\nu$ itself is hereditarily $\nu$-invariant if it names a subset of some ground model set (say, if $\nu$ is a real), so in that case the model is strictly bigger than $V$; and dropping the hereditary requirement means we don't get a transitive set. Although there is a bug that I just noticed - if $\nu$ is *not* a name for a subset of some ground model set (e.g. is a name for a set of *new* reals), I don't see why $\nu$ should be a priori hereditarily $\nu$-invariant! Dang . . . I think there is something interesting here, but I probably missed the "right" definition. Dang.

Comment: Generally, if $A\subseteq V$, then $V[A]$ will satisfy choice (assuming $V$ did, anyway). There's no escape from allowing things to be "only somewhat invariant", which will then lead you to some backwards definition of a symmetric extension, I believe.

Comment: Ow, good point re: first sentence. That said, pushing back against your second sentence, what about the following. For a finite tuple of names $\overline{n}=\nu_1, ..., \nu_n$ we define $\overline{\nu}$-invariance etc. in the obvious way. Fixing a single name $\nu$, we then look at the model consisting of the evaluations of all the names which are $\overline{\mu}$-invariant for some tuple $\overline{\mu}$ from $tc(\{\nu\})$. This guarantees that each element of $\nu[G]$ and so on winds up in the model, we can kill choice pretty easily, and I believe that the model still satisfies ZF. Thoughts?

Comment: Of course the idea isn't full generality - e.g. can use infinite tuples, etc. - but seems like a plausible place to start. (Also I've edited to indicate the badness.)

Comment: Then you really just talk about the automorphisms which preserve the name (or respect it, i.e. force the generic equality), and then take the filter of finite supports or whatever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Argh! Thanks a ton. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I spoke with Yair, he said it's fine (as long as you take this math with a large grain of salt, and not hold us accountable to any mistakes there!). Since you moved a university, drop me a line since I'm not sure that I have your current email.

Comment: Paging Dr. Schweber, Dr. Noah Schweber...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Whoops, sorry, didn't see your comment! Yeah, that email still works (theoretically I have it in perpetuity!) but my new email is schweber@wisc.edu. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Great. I'll try to clean up the file a bit and send you something tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original definition has a problem with the hereditary requirement, unless your name is something particularly nice, e.g. a name for a subset of the ground model. But in the latter case, you just get a model of $\sf ZFC$, since you essentially get $V[A]$ for some $A\subseteq V$.

In the comments you suggest instead considering something which is invariant under interpreting some subset of $\nu$ correctly, but this turns out to be quite similar to just the usual symmetric extensions: you have a name, and you consider all the automorphisms which preserve it (not necessarily actual equality, generic equality is all the same here), and then you look at things which get preserved when some subset of $\nu$ is being interpreted "correctly" rather than the whole set.

This just translates to an automorphism group of $\Bbb P$, and some normal filter of subgroups. At least in the "relatively intuitive case".